# Импорт модулей

Tags: python

Как правильно импортировать модуль python, если он самописной и доступ к нему нужно получать с разных файлов. Импортировать в каждом файле?

Answer (score 1):

импортируются как обычные библиотеки(impport (название файла)). Вы можете прописывать их в каждый файл где они вам могут потребоваться, и не беспокоиться несколько раз одит и тот же файл загружаться в память не будет, т.е. если в двух файл вы загружаете один и тот же модуль, то он загрузиться только 1 файлом а второй будет использовать уже загруженный в память модуль